# Publish custom object returns An unknown error has occurred OAuthException Code 1

Tags: oauth, facebook-opengraph

Using the Graph API Explorer I can reproduce this error using either the app token or the user token.

Call (POST)

```
/0000userid0000/mynamespace:Create
thread=aURLonOurSite
access_token=xxxxxx
```

Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

Running the token debug shows that I have the permissions:

```
Issued : 1346937448 (about an hour ago) 
Expires: 1352121448 (in about 2 months) 
Valid  : True 
Origin : Web 
Scopes : email publish_actions user_location
```

Comment: More info needed to make your problem reproducible … is the action approved by FB already, or are you using test users, sandbox mode, etc. And what does the debugger say about your Open Graph object URL?

Comment: This is live site with approved actions. You won't believe this, the opan graph debugger return "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped." when I have a capital letter int he host name!!! If I make it all lowercase then the debugger works. I'll test this out and let you know if i still get the error

Comment: That was the problem. Host names are not supposed to be case sensitive. Even Google.com fails till you make it lowercase: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.Google.com

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough but here i m going to show you an example which i had used on my previous project.

```
$params = array(
    'voucher'=>$plink,//'https://thevoucherlink.com/account/order/post.php?image='.$file_name.'&business_name='.$dd['title'].'&from='.$_SESSION['fb_uid'].'&to='.$_POST['friend_id'].'&msg='.$d['giftmsg'],
    'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken(),
    'message'=>$d['giftmsg'],
    );

$out = $facebook->api('/me/thevoucherlink:send','post',$params);
```

Here i have used `send` action for `Voucher` object. I think you haven't used object on your parameter.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks but the error was that open graph only appears to accept lowercase host names.